# quickBasic WINDOW statement

Tags: basic, dosbox, qbasic, quickbasic

I found this old book and in the appendix there are some QuickBasic programs that I want to try out.. the problem is that those were written on/for Apple Macintosh II and I use DosBox on a Linux PC.. The author of the book says that there are some differences in the graphics statements for Mac and IBM..

Some of the programs are just text input and output and those work fine on my DosBox, but whenever there is a "WINDOW" statement my DosBox outputs an error.. I have never before written anything in Basic/QBasic/QuickBasic and have been struggling with this WINDOW statement.. Here is the beginning of the program from the book that uses WINDOW statements:

```
WINDOW 1
REM A TWO STROKE ENGINE
WINDOW 2,"CLICK BOX",(201,50)-(400,450),1
PRINT "SELECT BY BUTTON"
WINDOW 3,"CURRENT DATA",(10,50)-(200,450),1
WINDOW 4,"DATA INPUT",(400,50)-(600,450),1
WINDOW 5,"ACTION BOX",(10,430)-(600,480),1
WINDOW 6,"EXHAUST TYPE",(400,50)-(600,450),1
WINDOW 1
100 INPUT"NEW DATA OR FILE DATA (TYPE N OR F)?";D$
IF D$="N" THEN GOTO 110
IF D$="F" THEN GOSUB FILED
110 WINDOW 3
CLS
```

can that actually be a user-defined subroutine? ..if it is, why is it named the same as the standard WINDOW statement.. Or is it just the syntax for Macintosh APPLE II quickBasic.. and it is different than DOC version.. the problem is that I can't find any manuals specific for Mac versions

in the programming manual for QB45 I see that the WINDOW statement has the following syntax: WINDOW (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) ... and in the 5th row of the program above the WINDOW statement has its third argument in this format.. i can only conclude that the first argument is supposed to be a window order number, the second would be the title of the window, the third is the standard WINDOW statement kind of argument, and the last is the color or something like that